# node_redis auth with pipeline

Tags: node-redis

With the following code, is there any situation that AUTH can be pipelined with other commands in node_redis?

This function is called every time node server accepts a request. In the callback function, other redis commands like get/set are issuing.

```js
var client = null;
var getRedisClient = function(name, callback) {
    var redis = require('redis');
    var redisInfo = getRedisInfo(name);
    if (client == null || client.connected == false) {
        if (client != null) {
            client.end();
            client = null;
        }
        client = redis.createClient(redisInfo.port, redisInfo.host);

        if (redisInfo.password != '') {
            client.auth(redisInfo.password, function(err){
                if (err) {
                    client.end();
                    client = null;
                }

                callback(err, client);
            });
        } else {
            callback('', client);
        }
    } else {
        callback('', client);
    }
};
```

What's the right way to send auth to redis server using node_redis?